# how to get value from unordered list dropdown in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using unordered list to make dropdown. I want to select some value from drop down list and want to use it in controller. Basically I should do this using  `<form:select>`  but it is now vary difficult to implement. Other part are ok and i am able to use them in controller but how to get the value from list i don't know.

I have implemented html code like this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/Web/password.html">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span> 
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="userName" type="email" required="" autofocus="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Applications</i></span>
            <div class="btn-group" id='btnn'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span data-bind="label">Select One Application</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" name="dropDown" role="menu" style="height:200px;overflow: auto;" >
                    <c:forEach var ="entry" items="${listOfApp }">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><c:out value="${entry }" /></a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/password.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String submit(@RequestParam (value ="userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam ("dropDown") String dropDown) {   

        System.out.println(entry+" "+userName);

        return "Hi";

    }
```

Is it correct method method to get value from dropdown using @requestParam as i did in this. If it is wrong then can someone tell what is the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Few Things:-

1.) At first place this could have been handled with `Spring` itself, if proper `commandName` have been used, `Spring` would have mapped it.

2.) Trigger some event on change of a dropdown, add it in javascript/jquery, have a `hidden field,` and `onChange` of dropdown option, your event should get triggered, and `set the value of selected option into hidden field`. use this hidden field in your controller.

Comment: @user2409128 search in google, you will find numerous live examples.

Comment: Basically all solution are given based on <form:select>. I did not get any solution based on <ul>

Comment: @user2409128 try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989146/event-handlers-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdowns)