# Why is .change() not working for the twitter-bootstrap select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a `.change()` on this select, but I'm having trouble.  I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<div class='btn-group twoColumn js-filter'>
    <button class='btn btn-info disabled'>Category</button>
    <a class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#' id='test'>
        <span class='btn_selected_value data-point-category'>
            All
        </span>
        <span class='caret'></span>
    </a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li class='selectAll'>
            <a class='filter' data-filter='#filterCategoryId' data-value='All' href='#'>All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class='filter' data-filter='#filterCategoryId' data-value='test333' href='#'>test333</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This `console.log` is not being fired:

```
$('.data-point-category').on('change', function() {
  console.log("what")
});
```

Where should I be placing the `.data-point-cateogry` class so I can use it via jQuery?

Comment: what is changing that you need to fire a function for?

Comment: That's not a `select` element, it's a bunch of HTML elements. `change` is fired by some native form elements like `select` and `input` only.

Comment: all you have are links and a button. nothing is changing.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no <select> options. If you are using Bootstrap, take a look here : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: Probably because it doesn't work on `span` element. You have to manually trigger the event.

Comment: There are a few examples of adding events to the Bootstrap dropdowns on this question. Might help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989146/event-handlers-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdowns

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I can use these events.  The problem is that i'm using bootstrap 2.3 and I don't think these examples apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event will not fire on HTML changing.

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

Instead, you want something like the following:

```
$('.filter').on('click', function() {
  console.log("what")
});
```

This would do what you want every time the dropdown option is clicked, which is practically the same as the value changing.